# app crashes when loading custom list layout

Tags: android

I am trying to create a custom list layout.  Here is the method that does it:

```
private void setUpList() {
    String[] items = {"item 1" , "item 2", "item 3","item 4" , "item 5", "item 6"};
    ArrayAdapter arrayadp = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, items);
    setListAdapter(arrayadp);       
}
```

and here is list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
</LinearLayout>
```

If I change R.layout.list_layout to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 it works fine but I need to use a custom one.  How do i do this without having the app crash.

Here is the crash log

```
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.srose.forumapp/com.srose.forumapp.HotelsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at com.srose.forumapp.HotelsActivity.setupListView(HotelsActivity.java:38)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at com.srose.forumapp.HotelsActivity.onCreate(HotelsActivity.java:29)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
10-06 17:59:55.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6941):     ... 11 more
```

new crash log

```
10-06 19:11:08.648: ERROR/ArrayAdapter(8552): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
10-06 19:11:08.648: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8552): Shutting down VM
10-06 19:11:08.648: WARN/dalvikvm(8552): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:366)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1970)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1228)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1139)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4351)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1889)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:938)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2040)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:383)
10-06 19:11:08.678: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8552):     ... 32 more
```

Comment: What is the output of logcat? It's hard to find the reason why application is crashing if you don't give an information about any exception and your code snippet is so short.

Comment: try adding this to your textView android:id="@android:id/text1" , you need an id for textView.

Comment: hi, tried that and it still crashses, I'll put the crash log in the original post

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your textView

`android:id="@android:id/text1"` ,

you need an id for textView , simple_list_item_1 has a textView with the above line. I think that is what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding android:id="@android:id/text1", remove the Layout tags so that it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```